# Parse <script type=“text/javascript” twitter python

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing

very long code..
Need parse screen_name:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" nonce="YjJmNTAwODgtODBmMy00YzQ5LWJhODItMmQwNTk0Yjg4MTI1">window.__INITIAL_STATE__={"optimist":[],"urt":{},"toasts":[],"needs_phone_verification":false,"normal_followers_count":2,"notifications":false,"pinned_tweet_ids_str":[],"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1174197230003208192/qK5cqalJ_normal.jpg","profile_interstitial_type":"","protected":false,"featureSwitch":{"config":{"2fa_multikey_management_enabled":{"value":false},"screen_name":"Vickson25435099","always_use_https":true,"use_cookie_personalization":false,"sleep_time":{"enabled":false,"end_time":null,"start_time":null},"geo_enabled":false,"language":"en","discoverable_by_email":true,"discoverable_by_mobile_phone":true,"personalized_trends":true,"allow_media_tagging":"none","allow_contributor_request":"all","allow_ads_personalization":true,"allow_logged_out_device_personalization":true,"allow_location_history_personalization":true,"allow_sharing_data_for_third_party_personalization":false,"allow_dms_from":"following","allow_dm_groups_from":"following","translator_type":"none","country_code":"us","nsfw_user":false,"nsfw_admin":false,"ranked_timeline_setting":1,"ranked_timeline_eligible":null,"address_book_live_sync_enabled":false,"universal_quality_filtering_enabled":"enabled","dm_receipt_setting":"all_disabled","alt_text_compose_enabled":null,"mention_filter":"unfiltered","allow_authenticated_periscope_requests":true,"protect_password_reset":false,"require_password_login":false,"requires_login_verification":false,"dm_quality_filter":"enabled","autoplay_disabled":false,"settings_metadata":{}},"fetchStatus":"loaded"},"dataSaver":{"dataSaverMode":false},"transient":{"dtabBarInfo":{"hide":false},"loginPromptShown":false,"lastViewedDmInboxPath":"/messages","themeFocus":""}},"devices":{"browserPush":{"fetchStatus":"none","pushNotificationsPrompt":{"dismissed":false,"fetchStatus":"none"},"subscribed":false,"supported":null},"devices":{"data":{"emails":[],"phone_numbers":[]},"fetchStatus":"none"},"notificationSettings":{"push_settings":{"error":null,"fetchStatus":"none"},"push_settings_template":{"template":{"settings":[]}},"sms_settings":{"error":null,"fetchStatus":"none"},"sms_settings_template":{"template":{"settings":[]}},"checkin_time":null}},"audio":{"conversationLookup":{}},"hashflags":{"fetchStatus":"none","hashflags":{}},"friendships":{"pendingFollowers":{"acceptedIds":[],"ids":[],"fetchStatus":{"bottom":"none","top":"none"},"hydratedIds":[]}},"homeTimeline":{"useLatest":false,"fetchStatus":"none"},"multiAccount":{"fetchStatus":"none","users":[],"badgeCounts":{},"addAccountFetchStatus":"none"},"badgeCount":{"unreadDMCount":0},"ocf_location":{"startLocation":{}},"navigation":{},"teams":{"fetchStatus":"none","teams":{}},"cardState":{},"promotedContent":{}};window.__META_DATA__={"env":"prod","isLoggedIn":true,"isRTL":false,"hasMultiAccountCookie":false,"uaParserTags":["m2","rweb","msw"],"serverDate":1614578006755,"sha":"9921d3a6d626dc45b0f5a65681ef95c891d815cd"};window.__PREFETCH_DATA__={"items":[{"key":"dataUsageSettings","payload":{"dataSaverMode":false}}],"timestamp":1614578006700};</script>
```

I`m trying this method

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = requests.get('https://twitter.com/home')
b = BeautifulSoup(x.text, 'html.parser')
for b in b.find_all('script'):
    wis = x.text.split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')
    if len(wis) > 1:
        data = json.loads(wis[1].split(';')[0])
        
print(data["screen_name"])
```

Result: KeyError "screen_name"
And this way doesn't work either:

```
import requests
import json


x = requests.get('https://twitter.com/home')
html = x.text.split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')[0]
html = html.split(';</script>')[0]
data = json.loads(html)
print(data['screen_name'])
```

Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update using full source html

```
for script in b.find_all('script'):
    if 'window.__INITIAL_STATE__=' not in script.contents[0]:
        continue

    wis = script.contents[0].split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')
    data = json.loads(wis[1].split(';window.__META_DATA__')[0])
    print(data["settings"]["remote"]["settings"]["screen_name"])
    break
```

---

you wont get `screen_name` it is only for current logged user, you have to `requests` with valid cookies to get the data.

btw for example above, it has multiple variable (json), you want json between `window.__INITIAL_STATE__=` and `,"devices"`

```
b = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for script in b.find_all('script'):
    if 'window.__INITIAL_STATE__=' not in script.contents[0]:
        continue

    wis = script.contents[0].split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')
    data = json.loads(wis[1].split(',"devices"')[0])
    print(data['featureSwitch']['config']['screen_name'])
    break
```

Comment: list index out of range

Comment: if 'window.__INITIAL_STATE__=' not in script.contents[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: please look full html code [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_7VT2MMmtlGbDZOtXtOnP_imSNiAWn-4/view)

Comment: @jorkia answer updates, try using `;window.__META_DATA__`

Comment: b = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
            for script in b.find_all('script'):
                if 'window.__INITIAL_STATE__=' not in script.contents[0]:
                    continue

            wis = script.contents[0].split('window.__INITIAL_STATE__=')
            data = json.loads(wis[1].split(';window.__META_DATA__')[0])
            print(data['featureSwitch']['config']['screen_name']) result; 'list index out of range'. `r.text this' session.get` using cookie it turns out the same code that I threw off

Comment: pls help me, I've been trying to do this for two days :(

Comment: see again above, it use `data["settings"]["remote"]["settings"]["screen_name"]`

Comment: to debug, save requests response to file, search for screen_name, if exist beautify the code using js beatifier then find the start and stop. next use json validator.

Comment: `data["settings"]["remote"]["settings"]["screen_name"]` doesn't work either

Comment: you have to find the json yourself, because it work in my side, see my previous comment

Comment: requests response [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1moMNgvqp3mVKu3jGR-ATEjLFOG8DUmuJ/view?usp=sharing) then I push it into js beatifier, getting [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oTZd_RN3aDUlABysRtYWFz0jjDjJE9rY/view?usp=sharing), next find start and stop, getting [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RdQhu4jvxRBIxUCXLZfekiB1zgD0sRDt/view?usp=sharing), and next step i`m understend ((

Comment: I try to make different variations, but always list index `out of range`

Comment: you help me ? (

Comment: I can't access your file, make it public. another easy way is using regex

Comment: i`m open acces file, check pls